# Variable scoping and sharing "global" reference dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Old-school programmer brand new to Python & pandas. The mutable datatypes are super cool, but they make it hard to intuit how to set up "global" reference data structures.

I have a bunch of reference data (currently tens of MB, but it will be hundreds of MB in final version). Quite a few different classes and scripts need to reference the same data. This is historical reference data. It changes very infrequently, through batch update from .CSVs.

It would be very inefficient to load this data into memory several times over. I want to load the data once the first time that it's used, then reference the same copy each time it's needed. Forgive the old-school references (I learned to program in the 1970s), but the "old way" of doing this would be to declare a GLOBAL pointer variable that points to a single copy of the several pandas dataframes that contain the reference data. The dataframes would be loaded from .CSV the FIRST time they were referenced, then all the different classes and scripts would just use that pointer variable to find the already memory-resident single copy of the data.

What I can't figure out is the best way to do this in Python/pandas so that all the different modules access a single copy (that doesn't get unnecessarily replicated).

I thought about a container class with methods to access a single copy of the data. The problem there is that pandas.DataFrame already offers such great features that I want all the other modules to have access to all the built-in methods of DataFrame. I see how I could make the "reference dataframe" an attribute of a container class, but I believe that would result in each different piece of code that retrieves that attribute getting a new COPY of the DataFrame, which could be 100MB+. All the different pieces of code referencing the same DataFrame don't NEED to be "protected from stepping on one another" because the data is read-only. But pandas doesn't know that and I fear it will copy the data for each independent class or script that asks for a dataframe object from the container class attribute.

I feel like what's needed is to somehow tell pandas "hey, this huge dataframe is static/readonly reference data, so don't copy it every time a different module asks for its own object handle to it, ok?"  Is there a way to do that?

Thanks!

```
from MyLib.refdata import RefData

rd = RefData()   # Create instance of container class that has my reference data

df = rd.OilPrices # returns 100MB pandas DataFrame object that was loaded
                           # by my container class. My fear is that pandas will make a
                           # copy of that giant dataframe so that if my code overwrites
                           # some of the data, it won't affect other users of the class who
                           # probably got their own copies. I don't want that. I want ONE
                           # copy.
```

Comment: "But pandas doesn't know that and I fear it will copy the data for each independent class or script that asks for a dataframe object from the container class attribute. ..."hey, this huge dataframe is static/readonly reference data, so don't copy it every time a different module asks for its own object handle to it, ok?" Um, just don't copy. Python never copies unless you explicitly tell it to. Can you give an example of what you are trying to prevent, actual code?

Comment: from MyLib.refdata import RefData

rd = RefData()   # Create instance of container class that has my reference data

df = rd.OilPrices # returns 100MB pandas DataFrame object that was loaded
                           # by my container class. My fear is that pandas will make a
                           # copy of that giant dataframe so that if my code overwrites

Comment: Please do not add code as comments. Provide a [mcve] in the question itself. In any case, *why are you afraid pandas will make a copy?* Are you *telling it to make a copy*?

Comment: I am assuming that pandas gives each user of the same class a copy of the dataframe object so that one user of the class can't over-write the copy that another user of the class is using. I want to make sure it does NOT do that.

Comment: Why do you think that? Are **you** making a copy? Pandas can't control how a class you've defined handles attribute access. In general, python will never implicitly copy anything. Now, users can write descriptors that make plain attribute access `some_object.some_attr` actually call a method underneath the hood which could do a copy, but if you aren't doing that, then you have nothing to worry about. I mean, this is fairly easy to test for yourself and you'll clearly see no copies are being made.

Comment: I was assuming pandas would "protect" each user of a class from having their copy of data returned from the class overwritten by another user of the class. Perhaps that was a foolish assumption. I was thinking I had to plan for this, but as you say I'll just try it and watch memory usage to see if there's really a problem.

Comment: No, pandas can't possibly have control over your user-defined class to begin with, so unless you are making copies in your user defined class (on initialization, let's say) then no copies will be made. You don't even have to monitor memory usage. Just do something like `a = rd.OilPrices; b = rd.OilPrices` then do something like `a.iloc[0,0] = 'foo'` then `print(b.iloc[0,0])` and you'll see `foo`. But again, python never implicitly copies, and does not use call-by-value semantics (nor call by reference, for that matter, rather, it uses call by object sharing)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dataframe (or any other kind of object, really):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})
```

An assignment like the one below will make the new variable reference the same object:

```
df1 = df
```

This is explained in detail in ["Is Python pass-by-reference or pass-by-value?" by  Robert Heaton](https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/)

To copy the underlying data, you have to make an explicit call ([`df.copy()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html)).